# Type mismatch when populating an Array

Tags: arrays, dynamic, type-mismatch

Could anyone tell me why this line is throwing up a "Type Mismatch" Error?

```
 Dim Req_Info() As Variant
Req_Info = xlWB.Worksheets("Sorted").Range("B1", xlWB.Worksheets("Sorted").Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

It had been working perfectly at one point?

Answer (score 0):

To Answer my own question, the solution was to replace

```
Dim Req_Info() As Variant
```

With

```
Dim Req_Info As Variant
```

Would anyone be able to explain why this is?